# Getting `Parameter Types cannot be optional` when using optional params in my step definition

Tags: ruby, cucumber

1. I upgraded to cucumber gem 4.0.0.rc.1
2. When I run a scenario that has steps with optional parameter, cucumber complains `Parameter types cannot be optional:`

Example:
step definition:
`Given I have a ({string} ) cucumber`

feature steps:

```
Given I have a 'blue' cucumber
Given I have a cucumber
```

1. Looks like a fix was merged in for this issue: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/pull/561
2. But, I am still seeing the error I described above.
3. I tried:
   `Given I have a \\({string} ) cucumber` 
   `Given I have a \({string} ) cucumber`

Comment: I upgraded from Cucumber gem `3.1.0`